# Probability of accidentally producing significant results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

I have a problem, which I think should be very common, but I mostly have been taught stochastic at university and most of my statistics knowledge is self-taught. Hence I have no clue on how to look for this on google or other search engines.

The basic question is, if I am testing a hypothesis against the null-Hypothesis on a significance level of `p*` (lets say `p*=0.05` for examples), what are the chances that I might reject H0 by accident. As far as my understanding goes, the usual tests estimate the Probability of seeing the given data even if H0 holds. So this would be `P(Data|H0)`. I am then rejecting the Hypothesis if `P(Data|H0)<p*`. Is this understanding correct so far?

One way I could model this is by estimating `P(P(Data|H0)<p*)`, however this leaves me with a probability of a probability, which looks weird to me, and I have no clue how to calculate this.

Or is my thinking to complex in this case and the probability I am looking for is just `p*`? However the formula `P(Data|H0)` is calculating a dependent probability and I am looking for an independent probability. This suggest I would need something akin to bayesian statistics to solve this, but I have only just heard of this term and would need lot's of reading to be able to use this by myself.

The reason I am asking this is, that in my case I am testing a great number of models each against the same `p*`. Now I want to know how many of the models that turn out to get pass this test are actually just false positives caused by the high number of hypotheses I tested. Maybe there is a better way to estimate this directly and my thinking is much too complicated here.

Comment: Are you referring to Type I error? Or am I oversimplifying your question?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the statistics jargon, so I am not sure. However looking at the explanation given on wikipedia, I think this is what I tried to say. So basically looking for the probability of a Type I error.

Comment: Then I guess you've also probably seen this line on the wikipedia page: "In the case of a simple null hypothesis α is the probability of a type I error. If the null hypothesis is composite, α is the maximum (supremum) of the possible probabilities of a type I error."

Comment: I hope that the ">" signs are typographical errors for "<", which means "less than."  Note, too, that in many settings $\Pr(\text{Data}|H_0)=0$, no matter what the data may be, showing that this probability is irrelevant to the test.  The test actually works by choosing a set of possible data values $C$ (the "critical region") such that $\sup_{H\in H_0}\Pr(\text{Data}\in C|H)=p^*$.

Comment: @whuber: fixed the typos... Not typographical errors, but too tired in the morning (half sentence in one direction, other half in the other). I am not sure about the rest of your comment, but I think I understand the basic Idea behind this. I definitely need more literature on Hypothesis testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p*, the threshold below which we would reject the null hypothesis, is normally written as $\alpha$, and is known as the false-positive rate.  A "false-positive" error is the error of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is actually true, and is also called a "Type-I" error.  However, the interpretation of $\alpha$ must be performed with some care; as this is a frequentist test, it means that if you repeatedly performed the test a large number of times where the null hypothesis is true, the test would reject the null hypothesis a proportion $\alpha$ of the time.  However this does not mean that the probability of having rejected a true null hypothesis in any particular instance of the trial is $\alpha$.  No frequentist statistical test can do this, as it as particular events do not have a long run frequency and hence you cannot assign a frequentist probability to them.

However, I think in this case, as you are repeatedly testing models, it is a bit like a quality control study, so the frequentist approach reasonable, and $\alpha$ is a reasonable answer to the question, because you are looking for the error rate of the statstical testing *procedure*, rather than the outcome of a particular test.

If you are interested in the probability of having rejected the null hypothesis incorrectly in a given instance of the test, then you will need a Bayesian approach.

Answer (score 1):

"By accident" is not well defined here. The p-value is the chance of getting results as extreme or more extreme than those you got in a sample if the null hypothesis is true in the population.

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to be more clear about the "By accident". What I meant is, assuming the null-hypothesis is true. What are the chances that my Hypothesis test will nevertheless reject it (p-value less than p*).

Comment: Hi @LiKao  that would be the p value. For example, if you  randomly generate two hundred sets of data in 100 pairs, and test each pair at p = .05, then you should get about 5 significant results.